Unsure how to store data with Swift structs?
I am planning on storing data permanently based on using the Habit struct detailed below, which uses the HabitEggButton struct to render a button using data from the Habit struct. Each Habit struct has a name associated and a boolean to track if it should be displayed.
Habit:
struct Habit : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var habitName: String
    var isDisplayed = true
}

HabitEggButton:
struct HabitEggButton: View {
    @Binding var habit : Habit
    @Binding var displayHabit: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
            print(habit.habitName + " button tapped")
            if habit.isDisplayed {
                self.displayHabit = self.habit.habitName
                print("Yes")
            }
            else {
                print("No")
            }
        }) {
            Image("egg_uncracked")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        }
        .supportsLongPress {
            habit.isDisplayed = false
            self.displayHabit = " "
            print(habit.habitName + " button held")
        }
    }
}


I googled online and to my understand there were a few options but I am not too sure what the optimal way of doing it would be. I stumbled upon things like UserDefaults and also SwiftData (which uses the @Model but I don't think I can use it with structs?). Any suggestions would be great! Thank you!

What kind of data is it, static or something the user can edit? Is it a small amount or thousands of objects? There are many possibilities like a resource in the app bundle, an external text file, a database etc etc but what is best depends on the requirements

@JoakimDanielson The app is a habit tracking app so the data would just be the habit names, and maybe some other information like how often they've been completed etc. Do you think I should convert my Habit struct into a class? Most of my googling led to SwiftData and I'm not too sure how to use that to store information with structs

Using a class and SwiftData is one way to go, making the structure Conform to Codable and store it as json in a text file is another possibility that might be just enough for your requirements.

Your options are:
AppStorage
Good for very basic data, like the high score in a game.
FileDocument
Good for text or image editors.
SwiftData
Good for box apps, e.g. recipe libraries.
